# Bulging product info

Tags: food-safety

Is packaged chunky guacamole: Ingredients: avocados, tomatoes & tomato juice, salt, onions, red onions, cilantro, lime juice,sea salt, jalapeno peppers & garlic. Plastic packed and bulging, okay to eat?  It's not expired and kept refrigerated

Comment: related : https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/81437/67 ; https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/37597/67

Answer (score 3):

Probably not; I wouldn't chance it. So: NO.

Something is producing gas, thus there is unexpected fermentation (by microbe action).  It is more likely to be bad than good.  Guacamole should not be fermenting.